# JPEG Huffman "DECODE" Procedure

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code

The JPEG standard defines the DECODE procedure like below. I'm confused about a few parts.

1. CODE > MAXCODE(I), if this is true then it enters in a loop and apply left shift (<<) to code. AFAIK, if we apply left shift on non-zero number, the number will be larger then previous. In this figure it applies SLL (shift left logical operation), would't CODE always be greater than MAXCODE?

   Probably I coundn't read the figure correctly
2. What does  `+ NEXTBIT` mean? For instance if CODE bits are 10101 and NEXTBIT is 00000001 then will result be 101011 (like string appending), am I right?
3. Does HUFFVAL list is same as defined in DHT marker (Vi,j values). Do I need to build extra lookup table or something? Because it seems the procedure used that list directly

Thanks for clarifications

[image: DECODE]

EDIT:

My DECODE code (C):

```
uint8_t
jpg_decode(ImScan    * __restrict scan,
           ImHuffTbl * __restrict huff) {
  int32_t i, j, code;

  i    = 1;
  code = jpg_nextbit(scan);

  /* TODO: infinite loop ? */
  while (code > huff->maxcode[i]) {
    i++;
    code = (code << 1) | jpg_nextbit(scan);
  }

  j = huff->valptr[i];
  j = code + huff->delta[i]; /* delta = j - mincode[i] */

  return huff->huffval[j];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not `MAXCODE`, it's `MAXCODE(I)`, which is a different value each time `I` is incremented.
2. `+NEXTBIT` means literally adding the next bit from the input, which is a 0 or a 1. (`NEXTBIT` is not `00000001`. It is only one bit.)
3. Once you've found the length of the current code, you get the `Vi,j` indexing into `HUFFVAL` decoding table.

Comment: By MAXCODE I was meant MAXCODE(I) and also nextbit procedure returns uint8_t this why I used 00000001 in question. I'm still confused because when CODE > MAXCODE(I) is true then CODE is shifted to left, so every time I shift CODE's bits left that condition will always be true like infinite loop :( Maybe SLL is not what I'm thinking?

Comment: plus, when CODE is shifted to left, should I write/replace NEXTBIT to most-right bit of CODE, if this is not true then I need to know what "literally adding" means :/

Comment: No, it won't always be true and will not be an infinite loop, since `MAXCODE(I)` is a _different value_ for each `I`, each time around the loop.

Comment: SLL is shift left logical, which is the same as multiplying by two. "Replacing" the least significant zero bit with the next bit (`NEXTBIT`), a 0, or a 1 is _exactly the same thing_ as adding the 0 or 1.

Comment: thank you for comments, "it won't always be true and will not be an infinite loop" so I can safely ignore infinite loop in my code? I added my code by editing QA. Currently it is not checking infinite loop, it could break after 16 iteration but if it is guarantee that it will not be infinite that would be great (even wrong DHT tables).

Comment: Last thing is that I used Vi,j values as HUFFVAL directly (without changing order of values), some libraries uses specific lookup tables, I'm not sure why they do that. I thought that maybe I'm doing wrong. For instance GO implementation: https://golang.org/src/image/jpeg/huffman.go

Comment: You can stop the loop after 16, since that's the maximum code length in bits for JPEG Huffman codes.